Is Multicat, the category of all small multicategories, a para-topos?
Is Multicat, the category of all small multicategories and related functors, (Def. 2.1.1. and Def. 2.1.9 of Leinster's book https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305049) a Joyal para-topos (i.e. a Cartesian closed locally presentable category)?
Motivations come from a new approach to complex systems and artificial intelligence.
Can you please give me some references to study and arrive to (possibly) prove this property?

I suggest you see this article How to ask a good question

Thank you Afntu for the suggestion. Can you please be more specific? Do I have to add any other information?

No: the category of small multicategories is not cartesian closed. A multicategory is exponentiable if and only if it is promonoidal: this is Proposition 2.8 of Pisani's Sequential multicategories.
